# Black screen, only TTY available

Tags: 14.04, xorg

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on the new Dell XPS13.
I never needed a login, I was just able to boot and my desktop would show up.
It doesn't anymore; I can still switch to TTY to get work done.

What did I do? I uninstalled/purged/autoremoved Google Chrome, the laptop then froze. After I cut the power and restarted it was like this.

I did not install Nvidia drivers (I did after it was broken to try and fix my laptop).
I have uninstalled Ubuntu desktop using Tasksel, but I do still have a graphical Ubuntu start for a couple of seconds. Very weird.

I've uninstalled nearly everything using tasksel (except the `printserver` and `tomcat` - which I can't uninstall `aptitude failed 100`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: i did `apt-get update` to try and fix the `aptitude` problem, which didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You may have updated the Display Driver. Most of the time the driver that you updated caused the problem. Try using the one that came with the ubuntu distro.

Comment: What do you mean? It broke before I even started messing around with the nvidia drivers (they have been removed now)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the graphics driver. Eg : sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*. And try to install new drivers from tty1 using sudo apt-get install nvidia-current or nvidia-common (depends on your system) and reset compiz and unity